# Why can't I send messages to the server through socket in the connect_to_target function while I'm able to send them in the while True function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I can't send messages to the server through socket in a single function but able to send in a While True: funtion.

**I found that it strange that i can successfully send messages through the while True: function send_msg,but i cant send messages in connect_to_target which is executed in GUIDisplay.py**
This is my main.py:

```
from rsa_controller import createKeyFiles, loadPublicKey, loadPrivateKey, encryptwithPublickey, decryptwithPrivatekey
import os
import random
import socket
import threading
from GUIDisplay import start_GUI_progress, popout


s = socket.socket()


def connect_to_server(id):
    host = "localhost"
    port = 23333
    s.connect((host, port))
    print(s.recv(1024))
    # send id
    s.send(b"__!" + str(id).encode('utf-8'))



def send_msg():
    while True:
        target_id = input("Please input the id you want to send to")
        message = input("Please input what you want to send to")
        encrypted_message = encryptwithPublickey(message,pubkey)
        msg_to_send = "_!@{}!@_{}".format(target_id, encrypted_message)
        s.send(msg_to_send.encode('utf-8'))

def connect_to_target(id):
    # Build up the message to send
    message = "_!?{}".format(id)
    # Send message to server
    s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

def recv_msg():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        if data.decode('utf-8') == 'target_connected_Success': # Got the response from the server
            popout('Connection Success!')
        msg_to_recv = decryptwithPrivatekey(data,prikey)
        print("Received: ", msg_to_recv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + "/keys/"):
        print("The key file is not existed.Starting to generate.")
        if createKeyFiles(2048, os.getcwd()):
            print("Generate Successfull!")
        else:
            print("Generate Failure..")
    print("Opening up the key file:" + os.getcwd() + "\\keys\\")
    pubkey = loadPublicKey(os.getcwd() + "\\keys\\public.pem")
    prikey = loadPrivateKey(os.getcwd() + "\\keys\\private.pem")
    id = random.randint(1000000, 99999999)
    print("Your id:", id)
    connect_to_server(id)

    # Start the process of sending and receving.
    t_send = threading.Thread(target=send_msg)
    t_recv = threading.Thread(target=recv_msg)
    t_send.start()
    t_recv.start()
    start_GUI_progress(id)
```

This is my GUIDisplay.py:

```
import PySimpleGUI as gui

id = 0
target_id = 0


def popout(title):
    gui.popup(title)


def start_GUI_progress(id):
    from main import connect_to_target
    layout = [
        [gui.Text('Your id:'), gui.Text(id)],
        [gui.Text('Hint:Please input the target id and click the connect button.')],
        [gui.Input(key='target_id'), gui.Button('connect', key='connect')]
    ]
    window = gui.Window("RSA", layout);
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == None:
            break
        if event == 'connect':
            print("Client started to connect：{}".format(values['target_id']))
            connect_to_target(values['target_id'])
    window.close()
```

That is,if i click the connect button,it should execute the function of "connect_to_target"function in the main.py,however,there is an error that:

OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using sendto) no address was supplied.

Comment: Err, because you are encrypting in one place and not in the other?